# How to use toArray() method in ArrayWritable - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

There is a `toArray()` method in `ArrayWritable` class in hadoop which should mean: convert this `ArrayWritable` to an array. But the syntax of of it is:

```
public Object toArray()
```

So how should we use this function? There is no documentation about it on doc package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the [ArrayWritable](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.21.0/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.java) has to be extended as appropriate

```
public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public TextArrayWritable() {
        super(Text.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the ArrayWritable

```
public ArrayWritable(Class<? extends Writable> valueClass) {
    if (valueClass == null) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null valueClass"); 
    }    
    this.valueClass = valueClass;
}

public Object toArray() {
    Object result = Array.newInstance(valueClass, values.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            Array.set(result, i, values[i]);
        }
       return result;
}
```

So, ArrayWritable#toArray would return a [java.lang.reflect.Array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) of the type specified in the `super(Text.class);` of the TextArrayWritable or the appropriate class.

Comment: ok, so how do I use toArray() in this situation? Do I make a Text[] and assign the output of toArray() to it?